# Jquery autotab-previous functionality is not working in Android Firefox

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

In **Android Firefox** only

1. In my form i have 10 number of number input fields of maxlength = 1 .
   Let i have entered some numbers .
   Place cursor before a number in any of the input field --> enter back space -> The number after the current field(where cursor is placed) will be deleted.
2. If i try to delete a number ,after deleting focus is not going to the previous input field .

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Please provide more detail, including an example of the javascript that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Focus should NOT change when pressing 'backspace', only when using 'TAB'.
So what you see is correct behaviour.

Comment: Place cursor before a number in any of the input field --> enter back space -> The number after the current field(where cursor is placed) will be deleted.
This is the BUG .
Expected behaviour is - Cursor should not go to front element and delete it . It should stay there .
How can i fix this ?

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand. I suggest, you file a bug report at firefox (I don't have a link, search for it.